# Ask (main) part of question in the title and don't ask it within the main text

Tags: discussion

Some users ask (main) part of question in the title and don't ask it within the main text. I've edited some of them till now, adding the title to the question. But I don't really know what is the best choice for editing these questions.
Any idea?

[Example](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4552/why-is-it-in-the-united-states-national-interest-to-care-whats-happening-betwe#).

Comment: That question is pretty short. I'm not sure it's a good example of a question.

Comment: quality of a question is not determined by "short" and "long" property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The body text of a question should be a full-fledged, complete, answerable question. The title should just be a synopsis. So I would agree with the edit you made.

Comment: And, a corollary: one shouldn't have to read the tags to find out, e.g., what country the question is about.